# How to calculate files in a particular folder based on file name in PHP

Tags: php, directory

I want to build a program for a photo studio that will calculate files in a folder for example I have a folder named Upload and it contains 10 files

- 7 of the files are named 1 5x7 and
- 3 of the files are named 2 5x7.

I want the program that will sum them up based on the first letter of the file name.

All I was able the do is to scan the directory and list the files in this directory.

```
<?php $dir = "/upload/";  $list = scandir($dir);  print_r($list);?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do the files have identical names?

Comment: The photo studio print picture based on copies and sizes so in a file named 1 5x7 the file character '1' stand for the copy while 5x7 stands for the file size

Comment: (From Review:) I improved the formatting of the question and changed some formulations for better comprehension.

Comment: you cant have files with the same name in the same directory how are there 7 files names "1 5x7" ?

Comment: @rtfm well.... technically you sort of can have the same filenames, given a \*NIX OS and having `5x7.xxx` and `5X7.xxx`, just not 7, but it's unknown as to the OP's OS or what exactly they want to do here.  Maybe they're inside different folders also. Edit: OP's comment says below they're on a Windows OS.

Comment: To rtfmYes but windows will automatically add up number(s) to make the file name different. E.g 1 5x7,1 5x7(2),1 5x7(3) and so on, that's why I said "I want the program that will sum them up based on the first letter of the file name."

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your requirements, this might do it ...

```
$files = scandir('/upload/');
$counts = [];
foreach ($files as $f) {
    $char1 = substr($f,0,1);
    $counts[$char1] = empty($counts[$char1]) ? 1 : $counts[$char1]+1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But in line 3 '$counts = [];' I had an error massage 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ...' How can I go about this

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?  The `[]` shorter syntax for arrays came out in PHP 5.4.0 which was released in 2012 (almost 6 years ago).  If you are using an older PHP, you should upgrade.  Until you can, use this `$counts = array();` instead.